# Changing Android studio default settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is it possible to change in android studio default settings as a custom setting for me ?
For example I use the word 'initialization' a lot, is there a way to let android studio auto complete it as the main functions ? 'String, int ...'

Another thing I use a function in all my activities is there a way to make android studio create my functions automatically every time I create a new empty activity ?

Hope someone finds an answer, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click File > Settings (on a Mac, Android Studio > Preferences) to open the Settings dialog.
2. In the left pane, expand the Editor section and click File and Code Templates.

> ```
> <here you can change the default code to whatever you want>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a code template for it. navigate to below link. It will help for u
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html

This https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/hippie-completion-expanding-words.html will help you to change your autocomplete configuration as u want (this example shows for web strom and u can do this in android studio as well)

Comment: the alt+/ didn't work or I couldn't know how to use it, any suggestions?

Comment: @raedghazal you can go to keymap and change your short cut key for relvent activites what u want